# Websockets - Avoid unknown connections

Tags: node.js, nginx, websocket

I have website X which runs a websocket server (socket.io, all based on node.js) and feeds clients with live data.

Now, competitor Y started connecting to our websocket server and straight out stealing data from it, displaying it also live on their website.

I've made numerous attempts at blocking their IPs, but they'll just keep changing it within a matter of minutes. (All kinds of AWS / cloud hosting providers). I check the referrer header, user-agent, accept-language, pretty much anything but all of that is spoofable and they do this already.

The websocket connections are proxied through nginx, if that helps.

What would you do?

Comment: have you tried authentication or message encryption?

Comment: User authentication? Guests can currently retrieve this live feed too. Message encryption? Decrypting would be all client-side, so it wouldn't take them too long to figure out, I think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Client X (the website) or client Y (the competitor) is meaningless. It's just a client. There is no reliable (i.e. impossible to hack) way to distinguish them unless you restrict IPs (which you already know that it fails). That's because client Y can easily construct a HTTP request/Websocket connection from scratch so that it looks like client X. And there's more: going down that road might be a waste of time and other resources. Eventually you will be hacked. The question is: which company has more resources to withstand this fight? :)

Authentication doesn't change much. Because client Y can authenticate as well. It's just instead of fighting with IPs you fight with user credentials. It might be easier though. You should try it.

So IMHO all in all what you end up with is constant monitoring and reactions. If they break law/agreements then you should sue them. If they don't then you can try this guerilla warfare. You might win eventually, who knows.

Comment: I saw this coming, I was hoping I could continue feeding the data to guests too in some way. Time to implement authentication then, this will surely slow them down and will make it easier for me to stop them.

Answer (score 0):

You could verify the [`Origin`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-10.2) header in the websocket request matches the origin of your clients. However, I'm not sure if it's possible to fake this header at all.

Comment: Of course it is possible. Actually there's nothing easier. You assume that clients are using browsers. While the reality is that probably there's a "request faking" server.

Answer (score 0):

An Authentication subsystem is a well-known solution to this problem to a large degree.